# how to access web page content using c#

Tags: c#, json

My url is 
http://www.whatsonindia.com/appi/user?channelgenre=all&context=applicationname%3Dsourcebits%3Bheadendid%3D0&dateselected=0&mode=getTVGuideInfo&pageno=1&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&starthour=0&totalhrdata=24&userid=-1

i try this

1.

```
string url=@"http://www.whatsonindia.com/appi/user";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
NameValueCollection myQueryStringCollection = new NameValueCollection();
myQueryStringCollection.Add("channelgenre", "all");
myQueryStringCollection.Add("context", "applicationname%3Dsourcebits%3Bheadendid%3D0");
myQueryStringCollection.Add("dateselected", "0");
myQueryStringCollection.Add("mode", "getTVGuideInfo");
myQueryStringCollection.Add("pageno", "1");
myQueryStringCollection.Add("responseformat", "json");
myQueryStringCollection.Add("responselanguage", "English");
myQueryStringCollection.Add("starthour", "0");
myQueryStringCollection.Add("totalhrdata", "24");
myQueryStringCollection.Add("userid", "-1");
client.QueryString = myQueryStringCollection;

var json = client.DownloadString(url);
```

2.

```
string url="http://www.whatsonindia.com/appi/user?channelgenre=all&context=applicationname%3Dsourcebits%3Bheadendid%3D0&dateselected=0&mode=getTVGuideInfo&pageno=1&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&starthour=0&totalhrdata=24&userid=-1";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var data=client.DownloadString(url);
```

both give error:(500)internel server error.how i resolve it? can anyone help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not your code that is broken. The url you pasted is broke and is returing an internal server error (500). So no matter what method you use to try and get the content the response will be the same. take a look:

http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/?page=single&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsonindia.com%2Fappi%2Fuser%3Fchannelgenre%3Dall%26context%3Dapplicationname%253Dsourcebits%253Bheadendid%253D0%26dateselected%3D0%26mode%3DgetTVGuideInfo%26pageno%3D1%26responseformat%3Djson%26responselanguage%3DEnglish%26starthour%3D0%26totalhrdata%3D24%26userid%3D-1&useragent=1&typeProtocol=11

SERVER RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

So after running a few tests first. Looks like you have to touch the url http://www.whatsonindia.com/ first. The first page sets a cookie that is required for the page you are trying to access. Without the cookie you get a http 500 error.

I dug some more and it looks like the cookies you need are:
userInfo={"userid":-1}
_woi-web_session=session value here

```
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "userInfo={'userid':-1}");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "_woi-web_session=[value here]");
```

I used firefox and the Firebug plugin to see what cookies the website was setting. i would delete one at a time until the page gave me http 500 error and came to the conclusion that those two cookies are required for the page to work.

Use this, it works i have tested it: How it works is, first it makes a request to the address http://www.whatsonindea.com/ to get the cookies that page sets. Then i make a request to the url you specified passing on the cookies from the first web request.

```
string baseUrl = "http://www.whatsonindia.com";
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(baseUrl);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
string cookiesVals = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

string url = "http://www.whatsonindia.com/appi/user?channelgenre=all&context=applicationname%3Dsourcebits%3Bheadendid%3D0&dateselected=0&mode=getTVGuideInfo&pageno=1&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&starthour=0&totalhrdata=24&userid=-1";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookiesVals);
var data = client.DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: can you tell how page set cookie. please give code for this